# Create a dynamic proxy of a jdbc Connection in order to override the commit or rollback methods

Tags: java, jdbc, connection, byte-buddy

I am working on an existing application which has extensive use of old-style jdbc SQL operations, i.e., SELECT, UPDATE, INSERT etc.

The application has a class managing data-fields, with a dirty flag to indicate that something has changed and needs to be committed to the database.

When the INSERT or UPDATE statement has completed without exception, and the commit has succeeded, the 'dirty flag' needs to be turned off.

For reasons of the current design and program flow, that is not completely trivial, so, I thought it could be possible to implement a proxy of the Connection used to write the changes to the database, override the commit method and ensure that when the commit is successful, the flag is set to off.

In other words, I want to implement, in effect, a java-based database commit "**callback**", so that I can subscribe to the commits of a particular connection, and act upon these events.

I was looking into byte-buddy as a possible means of achieving this, but in all the examples I've seen so far, one has control over the instantiation of the class being modified.

That is not the case in my situation. An instance of a type implementing java.sql.Connection is being created by the jdbc driver, often wrapped by another class used in a database connection pool (such as TomCat connection pool).

How can I intercept the instantiation of these objects, and override, dynamically, the commit and rollback methods?

Can I do it with byte-buddy?

Is there a better option?

Answer (score 0):

As I read I think you are having individual methods for all CRUD operations. Thus I dont think you should compleicate the logic. A much simler aproach :

1. Invoke all requisite methods from a try block sequencially
2. in the catch block (catch (Exception)) invoke rollback
3. In the Finally block, invoke commit.

This would simplify the logic, make it more readable and modulaize the code.

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at [Byte Buddy](https://github.com/raphw/byte-buddy)'s `AgentBuilder`? I think this is what would help you out here. Using this builder and a Java agent, you can change a class's implementation upon its definition by using the same syntax that you have seen in the examples. Only that you change (rebase) a particular class.